# How to enable Code Repository Azure DevOps Git in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

Can someone let me know why I'm unable to setup a code repository within Azure Data Factory.

Git is enabled in our Data Factory, see image. However, when I attempt try to access our Azure DevOps Git it is greyed out. Is this due a permissions?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The access is inherited based on the user's logged in credentials. You will need to have contributor access to the ADO project and a valid ADO license when attempting to configure ADF to integrate with ADO.

Can you go into the Manage>>Git configuration to see the details